# System.Data.IDbCommand and asynchronous execution?

Tags: c#, sql, interface, asynchronous, sqlclient

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
has methods

```
BeginExecuteNonQuery
BeginExecuteReader
BeginExecuteXmlReader
```

and

```
EndExecuteNonQuery
EndExecuteReader
EndExecuteXmlReader
```

for asynchronous execution.

System.Data.IDbCommand
only has

```
ExecuteNonQuery
ExecuteReader
ExecuteXmlReader
```

which are for synchronous operations only.

Is there any interface for asynchronous operations ?
In addition, why is there no BeginExecuteScalar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IDbCommand` does not have the begin/end async methods because they did not yet exist in the original .NET 1.1 release of ADO.NET, and when the async methods were [added in .NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery(v=vs.80).aspx) it would have been a breaking change to add those to `IDbCommand` (adding members to an interface is a breaking change for implementors of that interface).

I don't know why `BeginExecuteScalar` doesn't exist, but it can be implemented as an extension method that wraps around `BeginExecuteReader`. Anyway in .NET 4.5 we now have `ExecuteScalarAsync` which is easier to use.

Comment: I don’t see `IDbCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync()`. What [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) are you looking at?

Comment: Oh, you were saying [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalarasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I see.

Comment: @binki or [`DbCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223677(v=vs.110).aspx), which isn't quite as good as having it on the interface, but does support some polymorphism.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, I gave up on `IDbCommand` and switched to `DbCommand` everywhere just because of the `*Async()` methods on it :-). For the most part I’m treating it as an interface.

Answer (score 16):

I recommend to treat `DbCommand` and its friends as if they were interfaces when consuming database APIs. For the sake of generalizing an API over various database providers, `DbCommand` achieves just as well as `IDbCommand`—or, arguably, better, because it includes newer technologies such as proper `await`able `Task` `*Async()` members.

MS can’t add any new methods with new functionality to `IDbCommand`. If they were to add a method to `IDbCommand`, it is a breaking change because anyone is free to implement that interface in their code and MS has put much effort into preserving ABI and API compatibility in the framework. If they expanded interfaces in a release of .net, customer code which previously worked would stop compiling and existing assemblies which are not recompiled would start encountering runtime errors. Additionally, they can’t add proper `*Async()` or `Begin*()` methods via extension methods without doing ugly casting to `DbCommand` behind the scenes (which is a bad practice itself, breaking type safety and unnecessarily introducing dynamic runtime casting).

On the other hand, MS can add new virtual methods to `DbCommand` without breaking ABI. Adding new methods to a base class might be considered breaking the API (compile-time, not as bad to break as runtime) because if you inherited `DbCommand` and had added a member with the same name, you’ll start getting the warning [CS0108: 'member1' hides inherited member 'member2'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108)). Thus, `DbCommand` can get the new features with minimal impact on consuming code which follows good practices (e.g., most stuff will keep working as long as it doesn’t work against the type system and call methods using something like `myCommand.GetType().GetMethods()[3].Invoke(myCommand, …)`).

A possible strategy which MS could have used to support people who like interfaces would have been to introduce new interfaces with names like `IAsyncDbCommand` and have `DbCommand` implement them. They haven’t done this. I don’t know why, but they probably didn’t do this because it would increase complication and the alternative of directly consuming `DbCommand` provides most of the benefits to consuming interfaces with few downsides. I.e., it would be work with little return.

Comment: well put, this should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

Actually, creating async behavior equivalent to BeginExecuteNonQuery, EndExecuteNonQuery, etc. would be rather difficult task. Implementation of these APIs are far superior to simple spawning a separate thread, waiting for the database response and invoking callback. They rely on the I/O overlapping and provide much better thread economy. No additional threads are consumed for the duration of the network hop, database processing of the command - which is probably 99% of the overall time spent on the call. For a couple of calls it makes no difference, but when you designing a high throughput server, thread economy becomes very important.

I was wondering myself why BeginExecuteScalar is missing. Also, most of other providers, including ODP.Net for example, have no async API at all!

And yes, there is no interface for async operations.

Answer (score 3):

To solve exactly this problem I built a shim that calls async methods if they exist on IDbConnection.IDbCommand/IDataReader or call regular methods if they don't.

Source:
https://github.com/ttrider/IDbConnection-Async

NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/IDbConnection-Async/

Example:

```
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Person;";
            using (IDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                do
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        if (!await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0))
                        {
                            var name = reader.GetFieldValueAsync<string>(0);
                            Assert.IsNotNull(name);
                        }
                    }
                } while (await reader.NextResultAsync());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your are retrieving "one value" most of the time will be spent on 1) network hop to the database server, 2) database server executing command. Much more time than you will spend on say reading 1000 records into data set. So, I agree, it's not clear why there is no BeginExecuteScalar...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when I need to migrate my data calls to async methods. I've created an issue for future .NET Standard to [incorporate async interface](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20546). In the mean time, I've also created [a library with a set of interfaces and adapters for System.Data](https://github.com/adriangodong/system-data-async/).

Answer (score -1):

You may implement async behavior by your custom code, since it is not so complicated, as for your question - there is no any standard async operations for your goals.

Answer (score -11):

No there are not interfaces for them

The reason why there is not a `BeginExecuteScalar` is because you probably won't need an async call to get one single value back which should be very quick

Comment: That "one value" might involve 50 tables, a couple of views, maybe some stored procs etc.. It's most likely not the reason :)

Comment: That is the only reason I can give to myself and I think it is quite resealable..If for getting one value form your db you need to involve 50 tables there is something wrong with your schema and an async call won't help :-)

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso: Granted in 95% of cases you are right. But if you have such a schema, there is no way to change it on short notice, which only increases the necessity for an async method.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso The point of the async call is to enable nonblocking loading of that value. Regardless of table schema, any number of things can cause time to pass between when the client tries to send a command to the database server and receives a response. Async APIs let you handle the value loading in an event-oriented fashion rather than blocking a thread of execution.