# Async functionality missing from the IDbCommand interface

Tags: c#, asynchronous, idbcommand

Is this a reasonable way to add async functionality to the IDbCommand interface?

```cs
public async static Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this IDbCommand self) {
    DbCommand dbCommand = self as DbCommand;
    if (dbCommand != null) {
        return await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync().ContinueWith(task => (IDataReader)task.Result);
    } else {
        return await Task.Run(() => self.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm not entirely sure what the effects of using "ContinueWith" to fake the covariance of "Task".

Also, in the unlikely case that the incoming "self" instance does not inherit from DbCommand, will a thread pool thread be consumed and blocked during the execution of "self.ExecuteReader()"?

**Here's [a link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=b386c5c5ece49f44&id=B386C5C5ECE49F44%2121487) to my complete implementation of IDb extensions for async support.**

Thank you

Comment: Are you going to post your library as a nuget package?

Answer (score 4):

Just because it is cleaner, I would take advantage of the fact that you’re using `async` and `await` to do away with the cast in the `ContinueWith()`. `await` evaluates to an object of type `TResult` when used on a `Task<TResult>`. I was going to suggest the syntax `return (IDataReader)await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();`, but then I remembered that the compiler already knows that `DbDataReader` is `IDataReader`. Tested in VS 2013 and VS 2015 Preview (not sure what you’re targeting, but I assume all C# compilers that support `await` should work with this):

```
public async static Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this IDbCommand self) {
    DbCommand dbCommand = self as DbCommand;
    if (dbCommand != null) {
        return await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    } else {
        return await Task.Run(() => self.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

Now you’re using `await` to its fuller potential and saving a few bytes of code ;-).

The biggest concern with this implementation is, of course, the runtime type testing in `self as DbCommand`. In my opinion, [`DbCommand` should be used instead of `IDbCommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793539). This would let you remove the runtime cast. However, you probably wouldn’t have written this library if there was no problem with switching everything from `IDbCommand` to `DbCommand` and the runtime type check is probably performant enough.

### Visual Studio 2017 Syntax

With newer versions of C#, you can use the `is` keyword instead of `as` to write more concise code:

```
public async static Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this IDbCommand self) {
    if (self is DbCommand dbCommand) {
        return await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    } else {
        return await Task.Run(() => self.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `async` and `await` if you are using .NET 4.5. The way you attempt is right and hope you are handling the connections separately.

```
public static async Task<IDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this IDbCommand self)
{
    var dbCommand = self as DbCommand;
    if (dbCommand != null)
    {
        return await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    }

    return await Task.Run(() => self.ExecuteReader());
}
```